# PutSql - date format error

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm trying to read data from 'Teradata' and populate the same to 'Oracle' database. Please find below my flow,

'ExecuteSQL' -> 'SplitAvro' -> 'ConvertAvroToJSON' -> 'ConvertJSONToSQL' -> 'PutSQL'

Error message:
Cannot update database for StandardFlowFileRecord
due to org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: The value of the sql.args.7.value is '2999-12', which cannot be converted to a timestamp; routing to failure: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: The value of the sql.args.7.value is '2999-12', which cannot be converted to a timestamp

It seems i need to format the Date field before i populate the same in to Oracle. Could you please explain me which processor should contain this date formatting logic?

Furthur analysis shows that the particular value was truncated by the 'ConvertJSONToSQL' processor. 
input value to 'ConvertJSONToSQL' processor - "2002-02-04"
Processed value - "2002-02"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you may be running into [NIFI-2625](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-2625). In an upcoming release of NiFi (due to [NIFI-3430](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-3430)), you may be able to work around this by specifying the date format in an attribute, however that might not fix the truncated values you are seeing.

If you know the name of the field (or index into a JSON array, such as "7" above which is really index 6 in a JSON array) that contains the timestamp value, you could use [EvaluateJsonPath](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.EvaluateJsonPath/index.html) ahead of ConvertJSONToSQL, to ensure you retain the correct original value (let's say you call the attribute `sql.args.7.original`). Then after ConvertJSONToSQL you could use [UpdateAttribute](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.attributes.UpdateAttribute/index.html) to replace the incorrect/truncated value with the correct original one, perhaps by setting the attribute `sql.args.7.value` to `${sql.args.7.original}`.

Comment: thank you for the response. I have updated my flow as below, 

ExecuteSQL -> SplitAvro -> ConvertAvroToJSON -> EvaluateJsonPath -> ConvertJSONToSQL -> UpdateAttribute -> PutSQL

Now i can retain the original date value and send it to the PutSQL processor. The problem is the PutSQL processer is not considering any of the fromat as valid. I have tried the following different formats,

'2015-12-31' '2015-12-31 12:12:00' '2015-12-31 12:12:00:000'

All resulted in the same 'cannot be converted to a timestamp' error. Your advice would be helpful. Are there any work-around for NIFI-3430?